# How to zip the files using ionic?

Tags: zip, ionic3

Is there any ways to compress a file from `my_file.txt` to `my_file.zip` using ionic 3? I've found the ionic plugin that only can unzip the files but not to zip the files.

Reference:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/zip/

Anyone? Thanks for any helps or comments.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [client zip](https://github.com/Touffy/client-zip), You can fetch your text file in the downloadzip()
function , and this function will return you a zip blob file which you can convert into a zip file.